# add extra column to sql query result with constant value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, sequelize.js

I've a simple query which returns me list of ids..

eg. `select id from users;`

this returns me the list of ids, but I need another x column(not for the users table or any other table in db) with some constant value which I'll give. I can achieve that with Js or other language after querying the ids. But just need to know if there's any way to do it within the query itself.

current result:

```
id
---
1
2
3
```

expected result:

```
id      some_new_column         
---          ---
1            abc
2            abc
3            abc
```

where `some_new_column` and `abc`, both should be provided in query.

Not sure if this is even possible or not. Any leads/helps appreciated.

Comment: `select id, some_new_column from users;`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add the literal value to the `select` clause:

```
select id, 'abc' as some_new_column from users
```

Answer (score 2):

You just select it:

```
select id, 'abc' as new_column_value
from t;
```